# macos x - git oskeychain for storing credentials not working

Tags: git, macos, credentials

I`m running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and installed git (git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)) using brew.

I`ve checked out a git repo with the username within the URL "someuser@http://pathtorepo".
Every time if a git pull or push is executed the system prompt for the password so I want the system to store it using the following command:

```
git config --local credential.helper osxkeychain
```

However, the system still asks every time for a password. Does anyone have an idea, how the credentials can be stored?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing it out using the instructions given by [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) by running:

```
git credential-osxkeychain
```

specifically testing the `store` and `get` methods.

Comment: storing the credentials works well, I could verify it with the application "Keychain access". get I didn't try because I've noticed that I cloned the repository over ssh. My solution of the problem was to generate an ssh key and put it on the server that it won't ask for login information: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/how-to-store-ssh-credentials-in-terminal